# Using code field to display field from referenced entity

Tags: entities, display-suite

I have a content type of 'facility' which has an entity reference field ('manager') to a user. The user has a field 'telephone'.

Is it possible with a code field to display the manager's telephone number on the facility node?

I have played around with this but don't seem to be having any joy. I have looked for examples but can find none, so am beginning to think this isn't possible.

Any suggestions or advice most welcome.

(posted here at the suggestion of DS maintainer aspilicious)

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Use views and a contextual filter with the entity reference relationship you have created. Use EVA to get the block as field in Display Suite.

Display Facility nodes, choose the right format (I'd go for Unformatted List). Create the relationship in the right panel choosing two references, one that points from Facility to User, then one the points from User to Telephone using the first relationship.

Use contextual filters, provide default value Content ID from URL, validation criteria Facility content type.

Add a field "Title" using the second relationship. Now you have a block that you can publish on your page. If you need it as field in DS, use EVA to create it.